# Prevent the Firebase dashboard from showing data

Tags: firebase-security

I've implemented security rules for a Firebase and that's working great. But if an administrator can view any data then the data isn't private. And if the admin can - inadvertently or maliciously - modify or delete data, then the data isn't secure and the application isn't reliable. How can I prevent the Firebase data from showing in the Dashboard view?

Comment: It would help to define what an administrator here. It sounds more like you're describing an end user who has some supervisor level permissions, and like you're attempting to use your account dashboard as an improvised content management system? Also, although I personally find the delineation a bit annoying, this is a question about using software, not about programming or tools used to program.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to limit the data that is shown in the Firebase dashboard.

The Firebase Dashboard is meant for *system administrators*. So you should only give access to people who are allowed to see/manipulate all data.

In general it is a good idea to write your own application dashboard, which provides the administrative functions for your application. This would then be the dashboard that you give *application administrators* access to.